# Flex-box Footer Element Centered

Tags: html, css, dynamic-css

I'm making a user-resizable GUI window with a header that gains height through new elements, a footer with static height, and a spacer in between that automatically takes up the rest of the height. I attempted using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space), but the footer ended up vertically-centered. Picture:

[image]

If anyone knows why off the top of their head, it would be greatly appreciated. The element is being added to the page with javascript so the code is pretty messy. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please provide relevant codes along with your question.

Comment: The CSS is exactly the same as the answer in the link I provided.

Comment: You can set height to 100% and use a margin to make the footer sticky.

Comment: The window is resizable, and the content in the heading is dynamic, so that would be fairly difficult. Isn't there a simpler solution using CSS?

Comment: Please check your body has full height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the issue was, but I made a solution using the css `calc()` function.

HTML:

```
<div id="myWindow">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div id="subHeaderContainer">
            <div id="subHeader">
                Sub Header
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="subFooter">
            Sub Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myWindow {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#footer {
  width:100%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#subHeaderContainer {
  width:100%;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

#subFooter {
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
<body>
<header class="header"></header>
<main class="spacer"></main>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.spacer {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: For some reason that forces the spacer and footer to the right of the header, out of view.